# NetLogo - setting variable in calling breed in nested ask of same type of breed

Tags: nested, netlogo, agentset

I'm trying to set "parent" variable in a nested ask but without luck.

In code below I use an "outer" ask instruction "ask turtle 0" and below this a nested "ask other turtles".
In the nested ask I'm trying to set a variable of the calling turtle.

```
turtles-own [
  a
  b
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "circle"
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtle 0 
  [
    set a 2
    set b 3 
    show (word "(a, b) = (" a ", " b ")")
    ask other turtles 
    [
      show (word "(a, b) = (" a ", " b ")")
      set a a + 1
      set b b + 1
      show (word "(a, b) = (" a ", " b ")")
      ; Below isn't allowed. Message is: 
      ; This isn't something you can use "set" on. 
      ; set ([b] of myself) 14
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

The "set ([b] of myself) 14" instruction doesn't work and the message is "This isn't something you can use "set" on.".

Edit: added clarification below:
Let me elaborate a little.

Running the go procedure once gives:

```
(turtle 0): "(a, b) = (2, 3)"
(turtle 1): "(a, b) = (0, 0)"
(turtle 1): "(a, b) = (1, 1)"
(turtle 2): "(a, b) = (0, 0)"
(turtle 2): "(a, b) = (1, 1)"
(turtle 3): "(a, b) = (0, 0)"
(turtle 3): "(a, b) = (1, 1)"
```

However, what I would like to happen is that turtle 1, 2 and 3 can write "back" to turtle 0, so that when "go" procedure is run next time I'll set something like:

```
(turtle 0): "(a, b) = (2, 14)"
(turtle 3): "(a, b) = (1, 1)"
(turtle 3): "(a, b) = (2, 2)"
(turtle 1): "(a, b) = (1, 1)"
(turtle 1): "(a, b) = (2, 2)"
(turtle 2): "(a, b) = (1, 1)"
(turtle 2): "(a, b) = (2, 2)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A turtle can access the variables of another turtle but it can't change the variables of another turtle. So you will have to go back to the original turtle and ask them to change their own variable using `ask myself [...]`

```
ask turtle 0 
  [
    ask other turtles 
    [
      ask myself [set b 14]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is appearing because you are not using the proper way of setting variables in NetLogo. Instead, you should use:

```
ask other turtles 
    [
      show (word "(a, b) = (" a ", " b ")")
      set a a + 1
      set b b + 1
      show (word "(a, b) = (" a ", " b ")") 
      set b 14
    ]
```

That is because what you wanted to be `set ([b] of myself) 14` is inside `ask other turtles []`. When code inside that is run, it is applied to each individual turtle in the specified set (in your case, all turtles except turtle 0) until all of them has followed the instructions you gave them. So writing that `of myself` is kind of redundant in there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Pol ! 

However, your code does not solve the issue, namely setting the b value of the outer caller. 
The code you wrote just sets b of the "other turtle", not of turtle 0 which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question as if you wanted to modify the turtle 0 variable.  Another solution I think it could work apart from the one @LeirsW suggested, is using ```set b 14``` outside ```ask other turtles [ ]```, as that is nested inside ```ask turtle 0 [ ]``` that should affect only turtle 0.